# Unable to load module from Modulecatalog.xaml file

Tags: silverlight, prism

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to load modules from XAML file but not able to go through, my xaml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Modularity:ModuleCatalog
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:Modularity="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite">
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo
     Ref="ModuleAproject.xap"  
        ModuleName="ModuleA"
        ModuleType="ModuleAproject.ModuleA,ModuleAproject,Version=1.0.0.0">
    </Modularity:ModuleInfo>
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo
     Ref="ModuleBProject.xap"  
        ModuleName="ModuleB"
        ModuleType="ModuleBProject.ModuleB,ModuleBproject,Version=1.0.0.0">
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
            <sys:String>ModuleA</sys:String>
        </Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
    </Modularity:ModuleInfo>
    <Modularity:ModuleInfo
     Ref="MyDemoApplication.xap"  
        ModuleName="MainModule"
        ModuleType="MyDemoApplication.MainModule,MyDemoApplication,Version=1.0.0.0">
        <Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
            <sys:String>ModuleB</sys:String>
        </Modularity:ModuleInfo.DependsOn>
    </Modularity:ModuleInfo>
</Modularity:ModuleCatalog>
```

The exception which it is throwing is :

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was caught
  Message=Cannot add content to an object of type 'Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleInfo'. [Line: 12 Position: 27]
  LineNumber=12
  LinePosition=27
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CreateFromXaml(String xamlString, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean requireDefaultNamespace, Boolean allowEventHandlers, Boolean expandTemplatesDuringParse)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CreateFromXaml(String xamlString, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean requireDefaultNamespace, Boolean allowEventHandlers)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(String xaml)
       at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(Stream xamlStream)
       at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(Uri builderResourceUri)
       at MyDemoApplication.MyBootStrapper.GetModuleCatalog()
       at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.ConfigureContainer()
       at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.Run(Boolean runWithDefaultConfiguration)
       at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.Run()
       at MyDemoApplication.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
```

Any help on this is very much appreciated. 
I am using Prism 2.2 and Silverlight 4.0 for development

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Silverlight in a long time, but just quickly looking at your code, I think you have the following wrong

```
assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite
```

I believe that in my Silverlight projects I used the following

```
assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism
```

that is for the modularity namespace.
If this is not correct, just let me know and I will gladly help further.